# SQL: sorting according to 3 parent id

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

How to sort this table?
It depends to parent grp1 to parent grp3 to sort

here sample my table :

```
   Group Code - Group Desc - Level - Parent Grp1 - Parent Grp2 - Parent Grp3
   03       OFFICE SUPPLIES  1        null           null          null
   02       TOOLS            1        null           null          null  
   0000002  0000002          3         02            0201          null
   0201     HARDWARE         2         02            null          null     
   0301     PEN AND PENCIL   2         03            null          null         
   0000001  0000002          3         03            0301          null
```

I have example to my desire output:

```
   Group Code - Group Desc - Level - Parent Grp1 - Parent Grp2 - Parent Grp3
   02       TOOLS            1        null           null          null
   0201     HARDWARE         2         02            null          null
   0000002  0000002          3         02            0201          null
   03       OFFICE SUPPLIES  1        null           null          null
   0301     PEN AND PENCIL   2         03            null          null
   0000001  0000001          3         03            0301          null
```

can anyone help me sample query of my desire output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get what you want for your sample data by doing:

```
order by coalesce(ParentGrp1, GroupCode), level
```

EDIT:

As you add more data, you can extend this:

```
select *
from table1
order by coalesce(ParentGrp1, GroupCode),
         coalesce(ParentGrp2, GroupCode),
         level;
```

It might be a bit more complicated:

```
select *
from table1
order by coalesce(ParentGrp1, GroupCode),
         (case when level > 1 then coalesce(ParentGrp2, GroupCode) end),
         (case when level > 2 then coalesce(ParentGrp3, GroupCode) end),
         level;
```

Comment: Here is a demo fiddle per answer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dd2c/5. Works perfectly.

Comment: @Rahul i edit the sql then i want the grp_code 0301 next is 0000001 then 0302 next is 00000002 this the link.can you help me? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9487b/1

Comment: @Gordon Linoff here a link the sorting did not recognize :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9487b/3